# Getting a value from a related table entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have a database added these tables using the Visual Studio Entity Framework ADO.NET model.
[Database setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zw4dP.png)

Now I am able to retrieve everything from the first two tables given the code i have written, but I'd also like the name of the blood color instead of just the BloodColorID. How would I be able to do this? Here is what I currently have:

```
List<Person> Person= new List<Person>();
            Person= dc.Persons.Include(c => c.BloodTypes).ToList();
```

Comment: You can anyways access it by `dc.Persons.Select(c => c.BloodTypes.BloodTypeColors.BloodColor).ToList();`. Try it.

Comment: Oh so the problem is there are multiple blood types related to one person, so    
    BloodTypes is ICollection<BloodType> BloodTypes {get; set;} So it wont show 
    .BloodTypeColors. 

Or at least that is what I think the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: @carsgofast300 .Include(c => c.BloodTypes.BloodColor).ToList(). If BloodTypes is a list then do this .Include(c => c.BloodTypes.Select(v => v.BloodColor)).ToList(). Here is the documentation on include. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx